# Auto-fill Custom comment fields

Tags: comments, comment-form

Thank you for reading,

I added custom fields to the comment form, and saved the input in the DB, following this tutorial http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/08/adding-custom-fields-in-wordpress-comment-form/comment-page-1/#comment-115187

Now i'd like the meta-fields in the comment form to auto-fill after the user has commented once.

Just like wordpress does with the Name, E-mail and Url; once you've commented the value stays in the fields. However, wordpress does this with $commenter['comment_author'] and this array doesn't have the data I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store these values in cookies and fill them when you are creating form inputs.

So in `save_comment_meta_data` add something like this:

```
$commenter_data = array(
  'phone' => $phone,
  ...
);
setcookie('commenter_data', serialize($commenter_data), time()+1209600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false);
```

And then when you're creating form:

```
$commenter_data = isset($_COOKIE['commenter_data']) ? unserialize($_COOKIE['commenter_data]) : array();
echo '<p class="comment-form-title">'.
'<label for="phone">' . __( 'Commenter Phone' ) . '</label>'.
'<input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" size="30"  tabindex="5" value="'. (array_key_exists('phone', $commenter_data) ? $commenter_data['phone'] : '') .'" /></p>';
```

Comment: This code wasn't tested so it can be a little bit buggy, I guess. But the idea behind it should be clear.

Comment: I was hoping to do it with WP's functions. But I guess cookies will do as fine. Thanks a lot for the reply!